# Symfony - caching of database result sets

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, symfony

I'm using symfony framework and i'm trying to figure out a way to reduce database read action significantly, i've heard about using caching to serve data that is accessed very frequently, and the cache updates when the data is updated, this is pretty much everything i know about the subject, i'm archiving data to a different table and using views to merge the two table to get a union of the two tables
(eg:- tournament_current holds ongoing tournament's details, tournament_archive holds past tournaments details, a view called tournament merges and show the union of the two tables) i need to cache the tables/views(?) to avoid multiple database reads for the same unchanging data, so database caching / query caching(?) would be very helpful.

so how do i implement this in symfony

1. is there a easy to use bundle?
2. can i store the cache files on amazon s3?
3. is there an easy xml based solution to this? if so how would this compare to symfony caching?
4. i need these methods to be compatible with postgreSQL and doctrine.

Comment: You should take a look at symfony result caches, lazy loading and so on. When this is not enough think about a denormalize your model. I don't think there is a bundel for something like a cache file in S3 because this is a pretty wild idea.

Comment: Which version of Symfony?

Comment: It's better to use a Memcached (or an alternative) server for this. Doctrine has support for this.

Comment: @SpartakusMd at what point would doctrine cache not be enough and i will have to use Memcached?

Comment: @pinchboitriggeredaf Memcached is designed to keep your cached data and return it fast. You still will use doctrine's cache, just the storsge will be different.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for "second level cache "

You don't need any aditional  bundle  - it is in doctrine , you just need to configure it .

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/second-level-cache.html

Comment: +1 you think this would be enough for archiving data? and also how big will the cache files be for medium sized DB, file format etc? where will it be stored and can i store it on a external server eg: S3, there could be a bounty on this question in the future, if more details are needed

Comment: if it won't be enough, then  think about caching data on redis

Comment: more description in your comment would be helpful, at what point would you say doctrine cache is inadequate  and start using redis

Comment: There isn't   simple anwser   about  when switch to  redis. You need to decide by  yourself. Use need to use some kind  of  metrics tools to see detail about server/db load and then decide .Also   remember that when you write code  you have to optimize it  (lazy loading , too much db queries etc.)